# ListBox not updating

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox

I am using a ListBox in one of the windows form application. When the screen first initializes, I am able to add/remove item into the listbox. However, after I click on one of the buttons to change the content of the listbox, the listbox does not update the values. I tried putting the Listbox inside a Panel and Refreshing the panel to no avail. Anyone ran into same problem?

Comment: The standard explanation for behavior like this is that you are updating a listbox on an instance of the form that you can't see because you use the wrong form reference.  Hard to tell, can't see your code from here either.  Try adding `this.Show();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds as though the data source you are binding to does not support IBindingList.